# Qual o tipo mais rápido, e com maior economia de memória?

Tags: c, memória, otimização

Eu estou fazendo um jogo de navinha em C, e portanto preciso colocar em um vetor uma quantidade grande de projéteis.

Esses projéteis tem pelo menos uma posição e velocidade para fazer cálculos, e estou tentando decidir qual a melhor forma de guardar-los na memória para uso posterior.

Portanto ficam algumas perguntas:

Qual o tipo na linguagem C mais rápido para cálculos em processadores modernos?
Qual o tipo mais rápido que causa menos bagunça no alinhamento de uma estrutura e desperdiça menos memória?

Isso inclui variações de tipos (não é int vs float, mas também int8_t, uint_fast32_t, double, long double, etc...)

Comment: Uma pergunta básica: Você sabe realmente porque você quer otimizar isso? Me parece que você está tentando fazer uma otimização prematura e desnecessária.

Comment: Porque eu quero... Eita povo chato, no SO em inglês também essa perseguição. Eu perguntei porque sou curioso, vi os tipos novos do C99, e achei legal, e quis aprender, não sou iniciante, mas não uso C a muitos anos, e quis exercitar meus conhecimentos e aprender mais dos limites e cantos escuros da linguagem. Eu creio que a maioria dos programadores em C nem sabem que uma Struct pode ser maior do que a soma dos membros dela por exemplo.

Comment: O seu objetivo é (a) aprender os pontos mais obscuros da linguagem C, (b) ter o máximo de desempenho no seu jogo ou (c) ter a organização de memória com a menor bagunça possível? Em geral, estas três coisas são incompatíveis entre si e otimizar qualquer uma delas provavelmente vai implicar em sacrificar as outras duas.

Comment: Não vejo porque aprender como atingir o ponto (b), ou o (c) é oposto ao ponto (a). (mas posso ver como (b) e (c) podem ser opostos)

Comment: A pergunta do @Victor é pertinente e não me parece perseguição. Ela poderia te fazer economizar algumas horas ou dias deixando de fazer uma "otimização desnecessária". "Porque eu quero" não é uma decisão racional e objetiva de projeto. Você não pode culpar um usuário que quer te ajudar apenas porque você confundiu ele com sua pergunta. :)

Comment: Francisco Junior é que toda vez que faço perguntas de performance, o povo solta essa da otimização prematura, e não responde. Na verdade no SO em inglês (aonde fiz a mesma pergunta, e virou flamewar, com pessoas querendo deletar ou não a pergunta baseado na utilidade da otimização, ao invés de responder a pergunta) eu até pedi para deletar a pergunta, não vou mais trazer dúvidas exotéricas ao SO, vou pesquisar por mim mesmo, e ficar com a resposta para mim, o povo é muito chato e mal educado.

Comment: Ninguém está sendo mal educado. O @Victor foi educado e fez uma pergunta comum. Ele só quis ajudar. Otimização prematura é realmente um problema, você ignorando ou não. E se sua pergunta causou problema no SO em inglês, por que você não a modificou para postar aqui para evitar o risco de causar o mesmo problema?

Comment: Eu postei lá, e logo em seguida aqui, o flamewar veio depois (na mesma hora que o vitor postou o comentário dele).

Minha implicância não é com o Victor pessoalmente, eu até entendo porque ele perguntar, mas sim com a situação toda. No SO em inglês teve até moderador e usuários de altíssimo karma discutindo (tipo, gente com mais de 100.000 pontos)

Answer (score 9):

Se você está armazenando esses dados em uma região contígua de memória (ex.: um array), então usar o tipo com o menor tamanho que ainda "caiba" seus dados teria a melhor performance. Nos processadores modernos, o gargalo não está nas instruções, e sim na **cache**: um *cache miss* na L1 "desperdiça" 10-40 ciclos, na L2 mais de 600. Se você pode reduzir o número de *misses* [por usar menos memória] às custas de uma operação adicional ou duas (ex.: tipos que não se alinham perfeitamente na memória, conversão simples de `int` para `float`), a performance global será maior.

**Disclaimer:** dei minha resposta baseado nos meus conhecimentos teóricos, mas não testei na prática. Não posso afirmar com precisão qual é o *overhead* das conversões de tipo acima, e de qualquer forma sistemas reais costumam se comportar de forma surpreendente muitas vezes...

Comment: Mas gostei da resposta, é o tipo de resposta que estou procurando :)

Answer (score 9):

Antes de tudo, tome cuidado pra não fazer otimizações prematuras pois é muito fácil escrever um programa complexo e "otimizado" que na verdade é mais lerdo do que um programa mais simples e intuitivo. Na dúvida use `int` mesmo é vá cuidar de performance só quando você identificar um gargalo em seus testes.

---

Mas para uma resposta mais completa, o mais importante pra se ter em mente na hora de escolher um tipo de inteiro são as regras de coerção quando você converte de um tipo para o outro e as regras de o que ocorre em caso de overflow (números muito grandes ou pequenos)

- Para variáveis locais e parâmetros e valores de retorno de funções prefira usar `int`. Isso vai compilar para usar o tipo inteiro e operações aritméticas "padrão" da sua máquina.

  Isso vale mesmo se você estiver fazendo contas com caracteres. Não só você consegue usar EOF sem dar overflow, mas você evita de criar um monte de instruções extras para truncar os valores intermediários das contas de volta pra 8 bits. Por exemplo, note como as funções isalpha, etc, da biblioteca padrão recebem parâmetros int ao invés de char.
- Números `unsigned` são úteis se você quiser comportamento de overflow bem definido (wrap-around) ou se você estiver trabalhando com máscaras de bits. Fora isso, evite usá-los, mesmo que se você souber que o valor que te interessa é sempre positivo. -1 dar underflow é fonte de muita dor de cabeça (por exemplo,  `for(unsigned i=N; i>=0; i--)` vira um loop infinito).
- Se você estiver armazenando um monte de valores num vetor a largura dos inteiros ganha mais importância (um vetor de char gasta bem menos espaço que um  vetor de int) e a performance das operações é menos importante (você vai extrair esses valores para um registrador/variável local antes de fazer alguma conta neles).
- Evite tipos de tamanho fixo como `int8_t` etc a não ser que você esteja fazendo algo que exija um inteiro exatamente daquele tamanho. Não só esses tipos são cheios de casts extras (ver o exemplo anterior de int vs char) como esses casts podem ser mais caros se o tamanho não for algo comum na sua arquitetura.
- Se os valores dos seus inteiros puderem ser muito grandes, num ponto em que 32 bits ou 64 bits faz diferença você tem que tomar mais cuidado. Tem mais de uma alternativa que você pode usar (long long, biblioteca de bignum, vetor de inteiros menores, etc) e a melhor solução vai depender do seu problema, compilador, etc.

Comment: Na realidade, int é sempre 32 bits, long long é sempre 64, e long é 64 compilando com o gcc para 64 bits. No Visual Studio, o long é 32 bits mesmo em arquiteturas 64.

Answer (score 3):

**Nesse caso, não é a questão de mais rápido, mas questão de qual tipo faz mais sentido.**

Em geral, trabalhar com inteiros sempre será mais eficiente do que trabalhar com letras, porém do ponto de vista de programação, a não ser que esteja trabalhando com algo que exija extrema performance, é melhor usar o que é mais cômodo.

Em C, quando fizer sentido, é útil por exemplo usar struct para dados mais complexos em vez de apenas colocar de apenas usar um array com vetores. Um struct, por exemplo, pode guardar informação como o ultimo dado acessado de uma lista de um array (ou lista lincada) e, por mais que não seja tão eficiente do que usar dados puros, pode ser extremamente eficiente quando a quantidade de dados é maior, pois você já teria cacheado o dado, em vez de ter que varrer toda a lista procurando o dado que queria.

**Ok, quer saber mesmo qual é mais rápido?**
Bem, na dúvida, costuma ser mais rápido o dado que ocupar menos dado em memória, ou um dado que pode ser operado por operações do tipo bitwise. Mesmo nesse caso, não é só o dado que importa, mas sim a forma como o dado vai ser usada.

Answer (score 2):

Para números inteiros, o mais indicado sempre o número do tamanho da palavra do processador. Ele vai se alinhar direito na memória tudo mais. Como isso muda de compilador pra compilador, o mais garantido é usar `ptrdiff_t` e `size_t`, typedefs padrão para tipos inteiros com e sem sinal respectivamente, definidos em `stddef.h`.
Já para ponto flutuante, não tem porque não usar `double`. Em qualquer processador moderno ele é eficiente, e não se justifica usar o `float`.

Comment: Gostaria de adicionar a sua resposta, que GPU (processador de vídeo) usa apenas float, e nesse caso guardar dados que vão para o processador de vídeo em float é melhor.

Comment: Verdade, mas em geral você faz todos os cálculos na CPU, onde a precisão extra pode fazer a diferença, e só no final joga o resultado na GPU. Eu acho que no caso geral compensa fazer assim, mas obviamente cada caso é um caso.